# Wrong container height using relative size with em

Tags: css, height, font-size

I have a header which height I would like to calculate using em.

The height should be equivalent to 40px. I calculated the em value with the following formula: 1/16*40 = 2.5em

My body CSS is as follows:

```
body {
    font-size: 100%; /* = 1em */
    height: 100%;
}
```

The css code of the header div is:

```
#header_container {
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    height: 2.5em;
}
```

If I now check the result e.g. in Firefox. The built-in inspector show me a height of 45px. But I would like to have 40px instead. As I have read the formula for translating px to em is the following: 1/16*px.

I found why I have the wrong height; it is because I have an additional font-size:large; entry in my header css.

After removing this, I get the height of 40px. But if a e.g. make a font-size of 1.5 em. The header height increases to 60px.

How can I make a font size of 1.5 em without the height of the header changes?

Comment: the reaons being, you are INCREASING the font size by 50%. half 40 = 20 add the two together (1.5) = 60px

Comment: This question has been answered within edits on the question; please post your edit as an answer and accept it so that this can be closed.